# Subsonic : Self Join , Table Alias

Tags: c#, linq, subsonic, self-join

Is there a way with subsonic to preform a self join?

Comment: Are you using subsonic 3? ActiveRecord? SimpleRepository?

Answer (score 1):

There used to be a discussion on subsonic about this, now dead. It basically said:

> it is [not] possible with SqlQuery you might have to use InlineQuery
>   for this

Comment: I removed the link which was dead and seemed to be spammy now

Comment: This answer adds no value

Comment: @Gauravsa I found the archived copy of the original linked-to source and it ended up saying very little. But since I made the effort to find it I thought i may as well copy that into the answer. Feel free to downvote, of course!